# How do I properly install a package in openSUSE Leap?

Tags: software-installation, opensuse

I am a long time Windows user who just installed openSUSE Leap and I am trying to get my head around how to properly install packages.

I downloaded the very latest version of Blender from Blender.org and got "blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2" in my downloads folder. I was able to extract the file with Ark and I figured out which file is the executable, but now what?

Am I supposed to manually place this extracted folder in some "program" folder somewhere and manually create an icon for it? What about uninstalling it when a newer version comes out? I am totally confused and unfortunately, all my research so far hasn't yielded me a simple and easy to understand explanation of how installing is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you want to use a package manager (In opensuse, it is `zypper`) to install RPM packages built for that distribution.

For example, to install blender:

```
# zypper install blender
```

Uninstall:

```
# zypper remove blender
```

Update:

```
# zypper update blender
```

For more about `zypper`, you can go [here](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_zypper.html).

Alternatively you could try `yast2 sw_single` to search, select and install a software package.

For beginners it's not recommended to add software to the system (the recommended way is to use RPM packages), but it you want to do:

If you want to use the tarball you downloaded, you can extract it, and just execute the `./blender` executable, or click on `blender.desktop`. You can also link `blender.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/` (or `/usr/local/share/applications/` for all users) to make the icon appear in the application menu.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Zypper. I will check it out. So where do people usually manually relocate their extracted programs to? I don't know that I want to use my downloads folder as an application directory. Now I need to figure out how to make a shortcut. Thanks again.

Comment: I went in to Terminal - Super User Mode and entered zypper se blender and it found blender. I then typed zypper install blender and it installed the old version of blender that I could have just as easily installed using the Install/Remove Software. How do I get it to install the tarball of the most recent version of blender that I downloaded?

Comment: If you're getting old package, try `zypper refresh` before installing/updating.

Comment: I can't figure out what the secret is to directing zypper to the version of blender that I downloaded (2.78) that is in my Downloads folder. No matter what I try, Zypper keeps installing the older version (2.76) that OpenSUSE considers stable.

Comment: Go to https://software.opensuse.org/package/blender and get unstable version.

Comment: OpenSUSE Leap doesn't offer any new version OpenSUSE Tumbleweed does but when I try to install it I get an error that says "blender-2.79-1.2.x86_64 requires libGeneratedSaxParser.so.0.3()(64bit), but this requirement cannot be provided." and then it gives some choices for Conflict Resolution.

Comment: Since I have never been able to figure out how to install blender or move it to a proper folder, I will just run it out of the Downloads folder. How do I make the icon appear in the application menu? How do I get the icon to appear on the desktop?

Comment: @BrysonJack Just copy `blender.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and `~/Desktop/`

Answer (score 0):

You asked where people relocated their extracted packages to. Once you have extracted a program that's already been compiled and bundled for you (such as Blender), you can place it in the /opt directory. Here's a bit more info about that directory: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

You typically want to use your package manager (Zypper) whenever you can. This makes it much easier to update and also remove packages.

Comment: I can't Move To>Root>Opt. Move here is disabled. It is like I don't have permission to move anything into the root folder.

Comment: That is to save you: In UNIX you need administrator right (i.e.: "root") to install (modify, damage, remove) software. Despite of that you can run programs from anywhere; just add the directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Why not use the blender package provided with the distribution as a starting point?